# How to calculate average calls "timestamps" per day on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I need help calculating the average number of calls I receive per day on Google Sheets. I can use your help.

Specifically, I want to calculate average calls per day [count: timestamps] for weekdays and weekends, respectively.

Here is the link to the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnHxSuQeFcKWIYrZxHrKQFJQ0TNekNAGrlvY-CyfYdU/edit?usp=sharing

I have found several links that come close to the solution but nothing that solves it, e.g. http://yogi--anand-consulting.blogspot.com/2013/05/yogifrom-timestamp-column-compute.html

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google sheets is not Excel - please limit your tagging.

Answer (score 0):

The question has not been asked very well, it important to show your attempts and specifically what you're look for. But none the less:

Create a separate column in call sheet E:E with the formula `=weekday(a1)` this will convert your date into a day of week number (1 through 7). From that, use sum if `=SUMIF(F:F,"<=5") for your weekday, and`=SUMIF(F:F,">=6")` for weekwend